# Openpyxl dataframe_to_rows generating unreadable content error

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I created a fairly simple utility function that just put a dataframe into an excel worksheet, using the newer dataframe_to_rows option in openpyxl:

```
insertRows = dataframe_to_rows(df)
worksheet = workbook.create_sheet(title=sheetName)

for r_idx, row in enumerate(insertRows, 1):
    for c_idx, cell_value in enumerate(row, 1):
        worksheet.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)
```

When I open the workbook, I received excel's unreadable content error which is usually related to formatting. After some googling, I found that the answer isn't posted anywhere. So posting my fix below

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being related to the formatting of the numpy NAN values in the dataframe which the cell class couldn't convert properly.

A simple fix was to change the insertion code into something like the following:

```
try:
    if numpy.isnan(cell_value):
        cell_value = "NAN"
    elif numpy.isinf(cell_value):
        cell_value = "INF"
    else:
        cell_value = float(cell_value)
except:
    pass

worksheet.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=cell_value)
```